# How can a remote client request a page via http://127.0.0.1/?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, https, web-config

In my ASP.Net application running on IIS, I have configured URL redirects from http to https so that all clients access my pages via https. Web.config looks like this:

```
<rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^localhost(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^127.0.0.1(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

So basically, any remote request not from the server are redirected to the https-equivalent URL.

Now the problem is that some remote clients seem to call pages locally. Example: http//:127.0.0.1/Default.aspx. I know this because I'm getting custom log entries from Default.aspx that look like this:

```
   Default.aspx.Page_Load: 
   Not secure: http://127.0.0.1/default.aspx --> 
   Secure: https://127.0.0.1/default.aspx 
   Client: 219.85.53.164
```

Translation: the client "219.85.53.164" called http://127.0.0.1/**default.aspx** and was manually redirected to https manually.

How did this remote client circumvent my HTTP rule and manage to call Default.aspx unsecured and (as it seems) locally???

Comment: A remote client can connect to your server and in the HTTP request contains the line `Host: 127.0.0.1`. This is the only explanation for such an log entry I have. The client is most likely an attacker who tries to find hidden/non-public web sites running on your server.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I have added a new "URL Rewrite"-rule in IIS that blocks any requests that contain a "host"-header value with "127.0.0.1". Let's see if this did the trick.

Comment: I think you can check the log file first, which will record the URL and IP information of the request. You can view the original URL. It is also recommended that you enable failed request tracing. If the problem occurs again, you can find the reason for the problem in the log.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Robert's answer, I was able to successfully determine what is going on: HTTP requests with the "HOST"-header field containing something like "http://127.0.0.1/default.aspx" are being sent to the server.
To block such requests, I have added the following URL rewrite rule to my Web.Config:

```
<clear />
<rule name="Block_Host_Header" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^127.0.0.1(:\d+)?$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="AbortRequest" />
</rule>
```

I am not sure yet if the pattern matches all unwanted requests, but in principal it should work.

**Edit:** Nope that doesn't work because it blocks *all* requests to 127.0.0.1